# Java - paint method in subclass not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

I'm new to Java and I am currently developing a GUI for a Blackjack game. I am having problems displaying components on a screen via the paint method. The paint method is located in a subclass called play (see below). When paint is located outside play but inside BlackJack it works. Could someone help me?

```
public class BlackJack extends JFrame
{

.
.
.

public class play implements ActionListener
{       

    .
    .
    .

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        Font bigFont = new Font("HURTMOLD_", Font.BOLD, 20);

        g.setFont(bigFont);
        g.setColor(Color.decode("#52504D"));

        g.drawString("Dealer", 50, 80);
        g.drawString("Player", 50, 290);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(120, 76, 700, 76);
        g.drawLine(20, 76, 40, 76);
        g.drawLine(20, 240, 700, 240);
        g.drawLine(20, 76, 20, 240);
        g.drawLine(700, 76, 700, 240);

        g.drawLine(120, 286, 700, 286);
        g.drawLine(20, 286, 40, 286);
        g.drawLine(20, 450, 700, 450);
        g.drawLine(20, 286, 20, 450);
        g.drawLine(700, 286, 700, 450);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(50,113,71,96);
        g.fillRect(151,113,71,96);
        g.fillRect(252,113,71,96);
        g.fillRect(353,113,71,96);
        g.fillRect(454,113,71,96);        
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Play` is not a subclass of anything that Swing knows how to paint.  You can't just implement a `paint` method in your class and have it magically work.

Try adding `@Override` before the `paint` method

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
```

It will fail to compile.  The reason it does compile know, is the compiler is inferring the call to `super.paint` as been the `JFrame`'s `paint` method, which you really don't want to do.

Instead, try extending `Play` from something like `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method instead, then add an instance of `Play` to the frame, like any other component.

```
public class Play extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{       

    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Font bigFont = new Font("HURTMOLD_", Font.BOLD, 20);

        g.setFont(bigFont);
        g.setColor(Color.decode("#52504D"));

        g.drawString("Dealer", 50, 80);
        g.drawString("Player", 50, 290);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(120, 76, 700, 76);
        g.drawLine(20, 76, 40, 76);
        g.drawLine(20, 240, 700, 240);
        g.drawLine(20, 76, 20, 240);
        g.drawLine(700, 76, 700, 240);

        g.drawLine(120, 286, 700, 286);
        g.drawLine(20, 286, 40, 286);
        g.drawLine(20, 450, 700, 450);
        g.drawLine(20, 286, 20, 450);
        g.drawLine(700, 286, 700, 450);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(50,113,71,96);
        g.fillRect(151,113,71,96);
        g.fillRect(252,113,71,96);
        g.fillRect(353,113,71,96);
        g.fillRect(454,113,71,96);        
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

}
```

Comment: I made all the changes you suggested and it worked. Thank you sincerely MadProgrammer.